# Почему не работает метод получения объекта?

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с о следующей проблемой. Есть несколько дочерних классов, наследуемых от родительского. Они используют общие методы в классе MainActivity.  В нем я использую спиннер, в который загружается наименование лекарства (строка).

Сделал метод получения класса, чтобы обращаться к нему из разных методов MainActivity.

```
    public static IbufenForte getIbufenForteClass() {
    return new IbufenForte();
}
```

Далее в методе выбора значения из спиннера, получаю то что мне нужно

```
        syrups.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selected = syrups.getSelectedItem().toString(); //заношу строку из спиннера
            intervalBetweenReceptions.setText(getIbufenForteClass().intervalBetweenReceptions()); //тут все что надо 
                                                                                                                                   //получаю из соответствующего класса
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Теперь я хочу, чтобы при выборе в спиннере названия лекарсва, брался тот же метод только из соотвествующего класса. Но чтобы не плодить условия иф елсе, сделал такой метод

```
    public Object getSelectedClass() {
    selectedClass.put(getIbufenForteClass(), getIbufenForteClass().contentActiveSubstance()); //заполняю хэш мэп
    selectedClass.put(getIbufenClass(), getIbufenClass().contentActiveSubstance()); //ключ - объект, значение - поле с  
                                                                                                                                  //наименованием            
    selectedClass.forEach((key, value) -> {
        if (value.equals(this.selected)) {
            obj = key;
        }
    });
    return obj; // возвращаю ссылку на объект класса выбранного в спиннере наименования
}
```

Теперь в теории я мог строку

> intervalBetweenReceptions.setText(**getIbufenForteClass()**.intervalBetweenReceptions());

заменить на

> intervalBetweenReceptions.setText(**getSelectedClass()**.intervalBetweenReceptions());

Но увы, getSelectedClass() ничего не знает о методах выбранного класса, хотя объект возвращает.

Как можно задуманное реализовать в данной ситуации другим способом, потому как с моим уровнем знаний я могу лишь наплодить if else

Comment: Что-то странное вы делаете... Скорее всего вам нужен один класс для всех лекарств с полями для свойств (название, форма, противопоказания и т.п.). При создании объекта поля инициализируются нужными значениями и тогда на любом объекте вы просто вызываете геттер к нужному полю и он возвращает значение, актуальное именно для этого объекта (лекарства).

Comment: тяжело читать ваш код и понять что вы хотите

Comment: Каждый вызов `getIbufenClass()` или `getIbufenForteClass()` создает новый экземпляр объекта. Ваш код их плодит налево и направо, совершенно без нужды.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, тогда там где они вызываются мне нужно использовать название класса вместо intervalBetweenReceptions.setText(**getIbufenForteClass()**.intervalBetweenReceptions()); использовать intervalBetweenReceptions.setText(**IbufenForte**.intervalBetweenReceptions()); Но как тогда сформировать хэш мэп? Ведь я хочу, чтобы при выборе соответствующего лекарства в спиннере подгружался в выделенном месте соответствующий класс **IbufenForte** или **Ibufen**

Comment: @woesss у меня именно так и реализовано

Comment: @Style-7, сложно сформулировать вопрос без добавления кучи кода

Comment: А понять проблему и без подробностей, и без кода ещё сложнее. Что есть `getSelectedClass()` и почему возвращаемый объект не знает, что у него есть метод `intervalBetweenReceptions()`?

Comment: @woesss, автор еще похоже не добрался до общего предка или интерфейса.